# conditional break point in eclipse not working for a local variable?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to debug my java code. I am setting a conditional break point. However when I debug it shows the error "Conditional breakpoint has compilation errors".

The following is my code snippet:

```
public RecipientsDTO readRecipientsFromStream(InputStream inputStream) {

    ICsvListReader listReader = null;
    List<Object> list;
    Set<String> values = new HashSet<>();
    int numberOfDuplicates = 0;
    try {
        listReader = new CsvListReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream),
            CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);
        while (listReader.read() != null) {
            CellProcessor[] processors;
            if (listReader.length() == SINGLE_COLUMN_PROCESSOR.length) {
                processors = SINGLE_COLUMN_PROCESSOR;
            } else {
                processors = TWO_COLUMN_PROCESSOR;
            }
            list = listReader.executeProcessors(processors);
            String recipient = (String) list.get(0);                
            if (!recipient.contains("@")) {
                recipient = recipient.replaceAll("[ \\-\\(\\);]", "");
            }
            if (!values.contains(recipient)) {
                values.add(recipient);
            } else {
                numberOfDuplicates++;
            }
        }
    } catch (SuperCsvConstraintViolationException e) {
        log.error("Error parsing csv: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new ParsingFileException(String.format("At Line Number: %s, Message: %s",
            listReader != null ? listReader.getLineNumber() : "Unknown", e.getMessage()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error parsing csv: {}", e.getMessage());
        throw new ParsingFileException();
    }

    return new RecipientsDTO().numbers(values).numberOfDuplicates(numberOfDuplicates);
}
```

this is my conditional break point.

```
recipient.equals("1")
```

However it shows that the recipient cannot be resolved:

[image]

The following is my conditional break point screenshot from the eclipse:

[image]

Comment: Break point is for line 65, in your code what is the line 65?

Comment: @Karol this is the line number  65 in the code                 String recipient = (String) list.get(0);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditional line break point expression is evaluated before the code reaches the line. Since `recipient` is defined in line 65, you can't use this variable name in break point for line 65.

To fix it you can rewrite the line break point expression as:

```
"1".equals(list.get(0))
```

or move the break point to line 66.